# SVG не отображается на gh-pages

Tags: svg, github, deploy

```
<svg className={css.icons} width={21.5} height={21.5}>
   <use href="../../../public/sprite.svg#icon-vector"></use>
</svg>

Вот моя svg-шка
Локально все работает, на gh-pages ветку деплоится, а вот на живой странице нету
Как исправить?

(На шикарный путь к svg не обращайте внимания :D )
```

Comment: Вот путь и исправить, наверное...